# materialUI get class names without using withStyles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an app that renders components loaded dynamically from the database. I can render those components and everything works great, but I want to be able to apply specific styles to these components using `withStyles`.

Here's what I have tried, for sake of simplicity I'm modeling my database response with a JS file.

```
const dbResponse = {
    __styles: {
        myStyle: { background: 'blue' },
    },
    components: (styles) => ({
        component: 'AppBar'
        className: styles.myStyle,
    }),
};

export default withStyles(dbResponse.__styles)(createComponentFromSchema(
    dbResponse.components(dbResponse.__styles)
));
```

This will generate the AppBar component but not with the correct styles. The reason is obviously that what I need to pass to `components` is the `Map` that `withStyles` creates and passes to the children components. I could recursively clone the entire tree and replace the styles but I don't want to do that. I am using server side rendering and have access to all of the JSS specific pieces that are incidental to that scheme if it is helpful.